# Will a variable go out of scope when the function returns?

Tags: c++, scope

```
void main()
{
    File f;
    DoSomething(f);
    DoSomething2(&f);
}

void DoSomething(File& f)
{
    f.Process();
} // will f go out of scope when this function returns?

void DoSomething2(File* f);
```

Two questions:

1. As seen in the comment, will f go out of scope when the function returns?
2. Do you suggest writing function using reference or pointer? (I'm talking about **private** functions)

Comment: @AJG85, why removing the RAII tag? The function looks similar to RAII examples.

Comment: @AZ.: Where do you see RAII in action in this code? Do you know what RAII actually is?

Comment: @Matteo Italia, sorry I am assuming File is a wrapper for the actual file resource (it needs to be cleared), thus file f will auto close at the end of main, why it's not a RAII action?

Comment: @AZ.: sorry, I read/wrote RAII thinking RTTI (it's been a long day... :P ). Yes, `File` could be a RAII class, but I'd say that your example do not *specifically* targets RAII, but just scoping/destructor problems.

Comment: @AZ It was just for clarity as your question is really about variable scope. If you were designing your own file class or smart pointer using RAII then it would be the better tag.

Comment: `void main()` is actually useful for detecting books and tutorials written by authors who don't know the language very well. It's `int main()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. `f` *the reference local to `DoSomething`* will go out of scope, but this obviously has no consequences.

   The `f` *object local to `main`* goes out of scope only after the end of the `main` (which, incidentally, should be **`int`** `main`.

   To sum it up, references are aliases to objects, but the original objects retain their scope, as happens with pointers.
2. A common suggestion is *use references when you can, pointers when you have to*.

   In general I use references whenever I need a parameter to be passed - duh - for reference, and pointers e.g. when I want that parameter to be optional<sup>1</sup> (pointers can be `NULL`), when I'm accepting arrays, ... and in general, I'd say, when in the function I'm going to use the pointer *as a pointer*, not dereferencing it all the time.

---

1. although overloads and default values can be better than a `NULL`able parameter in many situations.

Answer (score 3):

`f` will not fall out of scope because it is an argument to the function, i.e., it was not created inside of the function.

It is preferable to take a reference if possible as it is guaranteed to be a valid reference and not null (yes, it *can* be null if you use some trickery and invoke undefined behavior, but then your program isn't valid anyway).

Answer (score 1):

Scope is a compile-time concept, not a run-time concept.  It refers to the visibility of names, not the lifetime of objects.

You have three things named `f`.  One of them is local to `main`; the others are local to `DoSomething` and `DoSomething2`, respectively.  For the first two, the scope (of the name, not of the object) extends to the closing `}`.

The *lifetime* of the object named `f` that's defined in `main` extends until `main` returns.  That's the only `File` object in the code you've shown us.

(And unless you're using a freestanding (i.e., embedded) implementation, it's `int main()`, not `void main()`.  Complain to whomever or whatever taught you that `void main()` is correct.)

Answer (score 0):

Of course not, `f`'s scope is the function `main`. It will get destroyed when `main` returns (ie when your program exits).

As to your second question, references are always better (insert grain of salt here), you are guaranteed you're never going to get a `null` and the syntax is cleaner (opinion, I know).

Answer (score 0):

When you call your "DoSomething" function, the do something function takes a reference of the f that's called from main. This means that the scope of the f in main is defined from the beginning to the end of main. The "f.process", by nature, does not go out of scope. It stays in the scope defined in main.

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1:**
you are passing the address of a file and giving it the name f (whose scope is only the function DoSomething(&f). Calling a member function of the File object will never affect the scope of the f variable.

Sort Answer = no.

**Question 2:**
references from my understanding is a Java concept, passing by "reference" in C++ is done by sending an object pointer as an argument. Whether or not passing by a pointer is the best solution largely depends on the context of what you are doing.

Sort Answer = maybe?

Comment: 2. Nope, it's not just a Java concept, references do exist in C++ and their use is encouraged in modern C++.